# Foreign key to dynamically changing record

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let's say i have a table with a lot of records "employee_hour", and another with alot less records: "turnover_export". `employee_hour` has a foreign key to `turnover_export`. However, sometimes the linked `turnover_export` gets outdated and needs to be updated for a lot of `employee_hour` records.

How it works currently (this way has become too slow):

For each `employee_hour` record where the linked `turnover_export` is outdated, a new and identical `employee_hour` record is inserted with a link to the updated `turnover_export`

How could i design a db/process to handle this as efficiently as possible?

Notable points:

1. Don't want to update the `employee_hour` records with the new `turnover_export` (because this means inserting new `employee_hour` records for each `employee_hour` record where the linked `turnover_export` is outdated, -> point 4 of this list)
2. Don't want to use triggers
3. The design should be tied as little as possible to a certain platform/db-engine
4. History should be kept, nothing gets deleted, updates mean new inserts

What I have thought of:

1. Link to a foreign key which is not an insert id but a UUID, then keep track with another col in `turnover_export` whether it is the one that should be used. *Doesn't work because a foreign key from a single column cannot reference multiple columns*

I know I haven't thought of or tried much but honestly i can't think of anything else.

Some context on what these tables are used for:

We want to report on the turnover generated for certain employee hours. We do this by getting a employee_hour record and then multiplying a certain column in this record with a certain column in the linked turnover_export.

Comment: *However, sometimes the linked turnover_export gets outdated and needs to be updated for a lot of employee_hour records.* Taking into account your "Notable points" we may consider that `turnover_export` must **NOT** be altered anycase. You must add a column which defines that `turnover_export` row is actual or outdated/archived, and create new row with updated values. After this some rows in `employee_hour` which needs to be updated nevertheless may be joined to newly created rows instead of old one.

Comment: @Akina Correct, when the linked `turnover_export` is outdated, a new `turnover_export` is inserted with the updated values. This means that the `turnover_export` linked to the `employee_hour` is now outdated and not to be used. So, how do I link these `employee_hour` records to the new updated `turnover_export` without updating the `employee_hour` itself ?

Comment: @Akina Do you know what performance implications your solution has? From what I understand, db defined foreign keys cannot be used in your solution.

Comment: *how do I link these employee_hour records to the new updated turnover_export without updating the employee_hour itself ?* ?? common UPDATE query: `UPDATE employee_hour SET turnover_export_reference = new_turnover_export_id  WHERE turnover_export_reference = old_turnover_export_id {AND another conditions}`. *From what I understand, db defined foreign keys cannot be used in your solution.* o_O Why??? I see no one reason for this.. *what performance implications your solution has?* I think that the amount of rows in `turnover_export` is so small that you cannot see any degradation effect.

Comment: @Akina Unfortunately, no update queries are allowed there. Because in that case we lose what `turnover_export` record was linked to the `employee_hour` record before the update. Your solution is basically point 1 of "Notable points".

Comment: If so then do the same - mark `employee_hour` rows as inactual and insert their copies which refers to new `turnover_export` row.

Comment: @Akina That is how it works currently yes. I should have added that in my post which i will do now. The problem with this implementation is that it is way too slow.

Comment: Partition the tables by the actuality column value, and add according hint into the queries for to access the partition with actual rows only (if the server won't do this automatically).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your particular application very well.  For a general history table, the primary key is usually some key plus the create date, descending.  That way, the "primary key" doesn't change, but you actually access the table record with a WHERE key = primary key LIMIT 1.  You access all the history records with a WHERE key = primary key.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` in question.